# Крестики нолики на c++

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь сделать крестики нолики на c++. Отрисовываю поле ставлю на поле крестик, пытаюсь поставить второй крестик но не получается, потому что первый крестик передвигается по новым "координатам". Помогите понять, что не так?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void DrawPlace(char icon,int x, int y){
    char map[3][3];
    
    int length = sizeof(map[0]) / sizeof(map[0][0]);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
         map[i][j] = '#';
        }
    }
    
    
    system("cls");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
     for(int j = 0; j < length; j++)
     {
        map[x][y] = icon;
        cout << map[i][j];
     }
     cout << endl;
    }
    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x,y;
    while(true){
        cout << "Введите X: ";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "Введите Y: ";
        cin >> y;
        DrawPlace('x',x,y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас поле каждый раз перерисовывается, вместо того, чтобы хранить все занесенные символы. Потому что оно локально хранится в функции `void DrawPlace()`. В итоге у вас не старый крестик прыгает по новым координатам, а рисуется новое пустое поле с 1 крестиком.

```
void DrawPlace(char icon,int x, int y){
    char map[3][3]; // локальный массив, который уничтожается при выходе из функции
}
```

Ну и по мелочам:

1. Заполнение поля игры символами `#` нужно сделать один раз - в начале `main` (также, как и создать поле игры), а не каждый раз при рисовании символа.
2. Зачем вы вычисляете `length`, если у вас известен размер поля?

```
char map[3][3];
int length = sizeof(map[0]) / sizeof(map[0][0]);

// лучше так
const int length = 3;
char map[length][length];
```

3. В цикле рисования не нужно на каждом шаге делать присвоение по фиксированным координатам `map[x][y] = icon;` - это нужно сделать 1 раз перед циклами.

```
void DrawPlace(char icon,int x, int y)
{
    ....

    map[x][y] = icon;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < length; j++)
            cout << map[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

И в конце несколько вопросов автору:

- цикл `while(true)` вы как заканчивать собираетесь?
- А проверять на то, что ячейка уже заполнена?
- А выход за пределы игрового поля?

Comment: На счёт выхода из цикла не беспокойтесь

Comment: :) Да я вообще за ваш код не беспокоюсь.